# How can i get a variable from .env to props in vue file?

Tags: laravel

How can i return a env variable value into a props default value in vue file?

This is my .env

```
API_BASE_URL=http://192.168.1.101:1025/doctruyenserver/
```

And this is my code from vue file:

```
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        dataUrl: {
            default: ''+process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL,
        }, 
    },
</script>
```

What i expected is it will return "http://192.168.1.101:1025/doctruyenserver/" but instead it return "undefined"

Comment: .env file is in vue project or in laravel project?

Comment: Laravel project. Sorry i'm still new to web dev and framework things...

Comment: Take a look: https://medium.com/@onur.kose/laravel-with-vue-and-environmental-variables-8be093105c69

Answer (score 0):

As an example you can create .env.development and env.production file in root folder of Vue App like,

```
  +-- node_modules
  +-- src
  +-- .env.development
  +-- .env.production
  +-- package.json

...
```

Inside the .env.development and .env.production, you need to declare variable beginning with VUE_APP_ like,

```
VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL=http://192.168.1.101:1025/doctruyenserver/
```

After that, you can use the variable in the Vue component like,

```js
 export default {
        name: 'Component',
        data() {
            return {
                 dataUrl: {
                     default: ''+process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL,
                 }
            }
        }
...
```

You can check out the official documentation [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes)